# Passing argument of ObjectForKey from incompatible pointer type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, compiler-warnings

Hey everybody! 
When I build this, i get a warning on the objectForKey... the warning says; "passing argument 1 of 'objectForKey:' from incompatible pointer type"
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark{
    NSString *streetAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
                                 [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:kABPersonAddressStreetKey]]; 

                               mapView.userLocation.subtitle = streetAddress;
}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the argument to kill the warning.

```
[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey]
```